# Postgres json index has no effect on query speed

Tags: json, performance, postgresql, indexing

I have been trying to create an index on a jsonb document all morning but I can't see any benefit from the index.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE modelling.triangle(id serial, data JSONB)
```

Here is my insert:

```
    INSERT INTO modelling.triangle(data)
    SELECT
    json_build_object(
              'x', generator.x,
              'y', generator.y,
              'array', generator.array_data)::jsonb
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        generate_series(1,10000) x, 
        generate_series(1,10000) y, 
        array_to_json(array_agg(array_elements)) array_data
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            generate_series(1,99) as key, 
            generate_series(1,99) as value
        ) array_elements
    ) as generator
```

And the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idxgintags ON modelling.triangle USING gin ((data -> 'x') jsonb_path_ops);
```

And the select:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT data->'array'
FROM modelling.triangle
WHERE data@>'{"x":10}'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't using the created index because that index was created based on an expression and you do not use the expression. The right query would be:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT data->'array'
FROM modelling.triangle
WHERE data->'x' @> '10'
```

You can read more about this in [JSON Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html).

Another way would be to create an index on data field with jsonb_path_ops

```
CREATE INDEX idxgintags2 ON modelling.triangle USING gin (data  jsonb_path_ops);
```

This way you can use your query unmodified but the index will be much larger.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't know exactly how to use the indexes.
My query has gone from 1000 ms down to .124.
Cheers.